Divide signup fee into monthy payments woocommerce subscriptions
I need to install the sign up fee divided in the monthly payments in the following manner:

Product price: 10$ for 3 months.
Signup fee: 3$

The problem that I'm having now is that the signup fee is being charged in the first payment and can't find a way to divide it in the monthly payments, so with the example above 4.33$ should be charged for 3 months (product price/3 + signup fee/3 every month). Currently the first month is charged 6.33$, and the following 2 months 3.33$.
Im using woocommerce subscriptions and can't avoid the subscription fee in any way, for example, I can't just divide the subscription fee and add it to the monthly price manually (client requirement...).
So basically I need a dynamic way of approaching this because the client has different subscription fees for different products, tried coding it but didn't quite work:
add_filter('wcs_recurring_cart_contents_total', 'install_signup_fee', 10, 2);

function install_signup_fee($recurring_total, $cart) {
    foreach ($cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];

        if ($product->is_type('subscription')) {
            $base_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price();
            $signup_fee = (float) $product->get_sign_up_fee();
            $duration = (int) $product->get_subscription_period_interval();

            if ($duration > 0) {
                $monthly_price = ($base_price + $signup_fee ) / $duration ;
                $recurring_total = $monthly_price ;
            }
        }
    }
    return $recurring_total;
}


In this case, you can't really use the default signup fee functionality. You need something custom, using a custom setting field for this signup fee amount. Then the fee (divided by the number of payments), will be added to the cart item price (so also to each recurring payment)…
